# Small program for rotating images

Tags: windows-xp, images, editing, rotate, crop

I need a small program (well, it doesn't have to be small, ... that's just there to avoid suggestions like Photoshop or Autocad) for cropping and rotating images by degrees.

*(have a bunch of scanned images that I'm just touching up for some paper)*

What would be the least-fuss suggestion for this ?

Platform: Windows XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnview.html). Image > Rotate > Custom. Not sure about the quality of the resulting image, though.

Answer (score 5):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) is nice.

Comment: It can rotate degree by degree ?

Comment: Yes it can. I use that feature all the time.

Comment: IrfanView is the best!

Answer (score 1):

[unpaper](http://unpaper.berlios.de/) can deskew, and `convert` from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can do cropping.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot - for Windows.

Comment: ImageMagick is for Windows, and I reckon it can do rotate by degree...

Comment: It can't do rotate, but unpaper can be compiled for Windows. Unfortunately the only precompiled version out there is 0.2.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) ?

Comment: Hardly small ...